# What is the cheapest way to get a visa for Myanmar in Chiang Mai?

Tags: visas, thailand, myanmar

I'm currently in Chiang Mai, Northern Thailand. I want to travel to Myanmar overland, so I can not use the online e-visa as it is only valid when arriving by plane at specific airports.

I checked various travel agencies and they offer a service to get the visa from the embassy in Bangkok. They charge between 2200 and 2500 Bath for a three working days service.
Is there a cheaper way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The day after I used one of the travel agencies to get the visa in Bangkok for 2200 Bath, I met someone who told me about the new Myanmar consulate in Chiang Mai.

I went there the next day and you can get the standard 28 day tourist visa for 800 Bath (3 days) or 1600 Bath (one day).

None of the five travel agencies I inquired at told me about this, either because they didn't know, or they simply didn't want to tell me, because they would lose my business.

I had looked online at the official Myanmar government site and wikitravel.org and found no mention of the consulate.

It was opened in July 2015 and is located near the north-west corner of the old city at:

```
9/4 Manee Nopparat Soi3,
Amphoe Mueang Chiang Mai, 
Chiang Mai 50200
```

Comment: Good to know for future reference.